# ORACLE EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FOR LOOP ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql, execute

I am trying to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE an entire FOR LOOP, but it is not working.
It is possible to do that?

```
BEGIN
     FOR V_ROW IN (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN,ID AS ID FROM (SELECT ID FROM T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION WHERE IDOPORTUNIDAD=2 ORDER BY ORDEN)) LOOP UPDATE T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION SET ORDEN=V_ROW.RN WHERE ID=V_ROW.ID;END LOOP;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'FOR V_ROW IN (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN,ID AS ID FROM (SELECT ID FROM T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION WHERE IDOPORTUNIDAD=2 ORDER BY ORDEN)) LOOP UPDATE T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION SET ORDEN=V_ROW.RN WHERE ID=V_ROW.ID;END LOOP';
END;
/
```

The second line works very well, but the 3rd line (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'FOR V_ROW ...') not works.  String inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is exactly the same as the 2nd line.

I need to execute a FOR LOOP for a parametric SELECT.

Comment: If you want people to look at your question you should try to make the code more readable. A single long string of everything in capital letters is hard for human beings to parse. Mixed case makes English more readable. Indentation makes code more readable, even if only because it removes the need to scroll.

Comment: Yes. The example do not need to be dynamic. The string has been built using variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is PL/SQL. Dynamic SQL is not. If you want to run PL/SQL code dynamically then you need to have it in a PL/SQL block *within* the dynamic statement:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN FOR V_ROW IN (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN,ID AS ID FROM (SELECT ID FROM T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION WHERE IDOPORTUNIDAD=2 ORDER BY ORDEN)) LOOP UPDATE T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION SET ORDEN=V_ROW.RN WHERE ID=V_ROW.ID;END LOOP;END;';
END;
```

That is, with `BEGIN` and `END;` (and a missing semicolon) added around what you had.

As @APC hinted, you can split your statement into multiple lines to improve readability, e.g.:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        BEGIN
            FOR V_ROW IN (
                SELECT ROWNUM AS RN,ID AS ID
                FROM (
                    SELECT ID
                    FROM T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION
                    WHERE IDOPORTUNIDAD=2
                    ORDER BY ORDEN
                )
            )
            LOOP
                UPDATE T_OPDM_PLANDEACCION
                SET ORDEN=V_ROW.RN
                WHERE ID=V_ROW.ID;
            END LOOP;
        END;
    ';
END;
```

It isn't obvious why you would want to do that with this example. If your going to use a 'parametric select' then you might be planning to inject that into the dynamic statement; but even that might not be necessary, depending on exactly what you mean and how you get the query. It isn't even clear why you would do this in a loop, or with PL/SQL, at all.

Comment: With this example I am trying to set an sequential ORDER to determinate ROWS inside a determinate TABLE using a determinate ID for that table.